# JavaScript: Is it possible to access an object inside an array of objects based on its key?

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
 EachRiskMappedToMaxImpact = [{
        riskid: 'R01',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R02',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R03',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R04',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R05',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R06',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R07',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R08',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R09',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R10',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R11',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R12',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    },{
        riskid: 'R13',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    },{
        riskid: 'R14',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    },{
        riskid: 'R15',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    },{
        riskid: 'R16',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    },{
        riskid: 'R17',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, ,{
        riskid: 'R18',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R19',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R20',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R21',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }
];
```

And I am wondering whether it's possible to access the objects inside of the array by using their keys.
For example:
I want to assign

```
'B. Very serious'
```

To the maxImpact property of the first object:

```
{
        riskid: 'R01',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }
```

I don't want to use

```
EachRiskMappedToMaxImpact[0].maxImpact='B. Very serious'
```

I want to access the first object based on its key riskid.
Is this possible?

Comment: Unless you know the specific index, you'd have to use an iterator, one way or another

Comment: If you want to access things by key, why aren't you using a dictionary instead of an array?

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't know what a dictionary is. I'll check it out

Comment: Why is this post being voted down?

Comment: I did not downvote it, but it's probably because the information is readily available with a little searching. You can google "javascript dictionary" or "javascript associative array". You could define, `EachRiskMappedToMaxImpact = { 'R01': 'E. Not significant', 'R02': 'E: Not significant', ...}`. This kind of data structure is very useful.

Comment: You can also search for "javascript access array by key" which shows some other approaches that are interesting (depending upon your needs).

Comment: If you must use an array you can use `.find` https://jsfiddle.net/0pr45wmj/ (just ensure you do a check to ensure the found object is not undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EachRiskMappedToMaxImpact.forEach( element => {
 if(element.riskid == "R01"){
    element.maxImpact = "B. Very serious"
 }
})


//where in if condition "R01" will be your key for which you want to search
//and after that set the maxImpact to your desired value
```

Comment: @NickParsons thanks I forgot, let me correct the ans

Answer (score 1):

As you said you want to access the first object based on its key riskid.You can use .map() to iterate through each element and make changes to your array.

```
var EachRiskMappedToMaxImpact = [{
        riskid: 'R01',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R02',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R03',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R04',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R05',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R06',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R07',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R08',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R09',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }, {
        riskid: 'R21',
        maxImpact: 'E. Not significant'
    }
];

var b=EachRiskMappedToMaxImpact.map(function(a){
  if(a.riskid=='R01'){
    a.maxImpact='B. Very serious'
  }

  return a;
});
console.log(b);
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/piyubanuhu/1/edit?js,console)